# Matlab sequential multiplication 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I've got a NxNxM matrix and I want to multiply all of them in order to have an NxN matrix, like

```
A(:,:,1) * A(:,:,2) * A(:,:,3) * ... A(:,:,M)
```

Is there a function doing this? Or should I use a for cycle?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to perform and element-wise multiplication, not a matrix multiplication between the pages, right? 'Cause your notation might suggest otherwise.

Comment: In case you are talking about element-wise product along the 3rd dimension, I'd recommend ```prod(A,3)```.

Comment: I'm talking about matricial multiplication, not element-by-element. If it would be element-wise, the Matlab multiplication should be `.*`

Comment: In which order you want the multiplications to be carried out?

Comment: According to the matricial multiplication properties. A1 = A(:,:,2)* A(:,:,3) and then the resoult A(:,:,1)*A. But matlab already follow this order. If I have the matrix A 3x3x3 and i do A(:,:,1)*A(:,:,2)*A(:,:,3) he gives me already the correct result (a single matrix NxN). I just need to generalize this operation in case I don't know how many matrices I have and I'm not sure if there exists a function doing that (like prod doing the element-wise multiplication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I can think of, using plain `Matlab` code:

```
out = A(:,:,1);
for jj = 2:size(A,3)
    out = out*A(:,:,jj);
end
```

Alternatively, with the aid of the `Symbolic Math Toolbox`, the `fold` (help [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fold.html)) function comes to the rescue:

```
res = fold(@mtimes, squeeze( num2cell(A, [1,2]) ))
```

where `num2cell` with the additional parameter `[1,2]`converts the 3D matrix into a cell array containing the individual pages and `squeeze` gets rid of the singleton dimensions. `@mtimes` is the handle of the built-in function that takes care of the matrix multiplication.

I haven't checked, but I suspect the approach based on `fold` is going to be more memory intensive and overall slower than the plain `for` loop, as it involves a conversion to cell array. And it requires a toolbox, of course.

Comment: There is not going to be any other approach. You have to do each matrix multiplication in turn.

Comment: @CrisLuengo managed to find another way to do it, taking advantage of the ```fold``` function.

Comment: I'm not sure `squeeze` is necessary there. `fold` is just an expensive way to do a loop. It's more expensive because it's repeatedly calling a function, the JIT cannot do much there to speed up the code. But in any case, it's essentially the same thing. You're still applying the individual matrix multiplications. There's no way around that, there's no way to save on computations by combining all the matrix multiplications into a single operation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo squeeze is necessary. The solution involving fold is indeed more expensive. Just thought it was nice to mention it.